# how to install pytorch and torchvision in raspberry pi4?

Tags: python

I try to use yolov5 on my raspberry pi4 model b ,but i have a problem in installing pytorch , I have followed many tutorials but nothing solves the problem , it show me this error message

```
requirements: torch>=1.7.0 not found and is required by YOLOv5, attempting auto-update...
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.7.0 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.7.0
requirements: Command 'pip install 'torch>=1.7.0'' returned non-zero exit status 1.
requirements: torchvision>=0.8.1 not found and is required by YOLOv5, attempting auto-update...
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision>=0.8.1 (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision>=0.8.1
requirements: Command 'pip install 'torchvision>=0.8.1'' returned non-zero exit status 1.
YOLOv5 v5.0-372-g808bcad torch 1.7.0a0+e85d494 CPU
```

python version used is 3.8
Any help would be appreciated